# Emploi de "y" dans "d'y retard"

Tags: y

Dans un e-mail reçu :

> Bonsoir, voici mon devoir maison.
> Je m'excuse d'y retard.

Je ne comprends pas l'emploi de "d'y retard". Il s'agit d'une faute, non ?

Comment: C'est peut-être un allemand ;-)

Comment: Personne ne relève le "devoir maison", c'est pourtant un terme que je n'ai jamais entendu moi-même. Après recherche il semble que cela soit lié à ma situation géographique et/ou à mon age. Durant toute ma scolarité en Belgique des années 80 à 2000, tout le monde a toujours appelé ça "devoir", tout simplement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectivement, on devrait dire :

> Je m'excuse du retard.

Cela peut être soit une grosse faute d'inattention, soit une mauvaise autocorrection si l'email a été envoyé depuis un téléphone.